# Prevent Firefox from unloading specific tabs

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-profile

Starting in [v93](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2021/10/tab-unloading-in-firefox-93/), Firefox introduced a [tab unload](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/unload-inactive-tabs-save-system-memory-firefox) feature.

I generally like it, but it always unloads those tabs that are most important to me.

Is there some way - either setting or addon - to "protect" a tab so it is not considered for unloading? (I don't want to disable the feature, just to protect certain tabs.)

(My environment: linux, firefox 98.)

Comment: Could you try pinning the tabs? Also obviously the best solution would be to install more RAM on your machine.

Comment: You can disable this feature from firefox and install the Auto Tab Discard add-on, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-tab-discard/ . It has an option to whitelist domains and also auto unloads tabs after x seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of Chrome, Edge, and Firefox (probably others because I think it was rolled out during the dev-tools excitement).

Get into options and search for "memory saver".

You might want to tag this for Chrome and Edge, also. In Edge, it uses a different name, but searching for "memory" pulls it up: it just saves memory and energy by de-loading tabs.

I think it's a nice green effect, and I keep this on in Edge, but I turn it off in Canary: different browser, different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way (circa 2023) to protect tabs.

Personally, I'm no longer using the feature; I use the [Auto Tab Discard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-tab-discard) extension instead. (Thanks to @ServiceDeskBunny in the comments above.)