# Disable Firefox's tab unloading feature

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-profile

Starting in [v93](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2021/10/tab-unloading-in-firefox-93/), Firefox introduced a [tab unload](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/unload-inactive-tabs-save-system-memory-firefox) feature.

In a [previous](https://superuser.com/q/1713218/904549) question I asked whether it's possible to disable this feature for specific tabs. (That does not seem possible.)

After using it for a while, I don't think this feature works as advertised, and it's more of a nuisance than a help.

So: can we disable this feature **completely**?

Comment: Curious why you are disabling it? Is it because you already are using Auto Tab Discard? I am doing that for this reason. I want to control the rules for discarding there instead.

Comment: @Ahmed No I'm not using any extensions. Like I said above, this feature does not work properly. It always unloads tabs that are most important to me. A tab that is "important" is not necessarily one that I use often - e.g. a mail app that I use a few times a day will be unloaded because it's relatively "unused", but once I'm logged in I don't want it to be unloaded. And there's no "protect this tab from unloading" feature.

Comment: Yeah better off turning off native unload and use an extension to manage it with exceptions and timings. ATB is awesome and Sidebery has some stuff to it too.

Comment: @Ahmed Thanks for the tip, I'll try it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- open `about:config` page
- set `browser.tabs.unloadOnLowMemory` to `false`